# How to avoid a page refresh when CheckBox selected in repeater in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an asp.net web page with a repeater control, how can I avoid a complete page refresh when I select a checkbox in the header to check all checkboxes in the item template rows?

My project is based on asp.net C#, with SQL Server as database.

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_product_detail" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_product_detail_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_product_detail_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                              <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_select" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_select_CheckedChanged"/> </td>
                              <th>SubCategory</th>
                              <th>Product Name</th>
                              <th>Product image</th>
                              <th>Product Price</th>
                              <th>in stock</th>
                              <th>Type for</th>
                              <th>Action</th>
                   </tr>                  
            </thead>
            <tbody>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>  
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" /> 
                 <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# ("int_product_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
             <td> 
                 <asp:Label ID="lbl_sub_cate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("txt_sub_category_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_sub_category" Width="100px" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "txt_sub_category_name") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" > </asp:DropDownList>

             </td>

            <td> <asp:Label ID="lbl_product_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("txt_product_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_product_name" BackColor="#d4d0c8" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "txt_product_name")%>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td> <%--<asp:Label ID="lbl_product_image" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_img_small") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                  <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="50px" Width="50px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("product_img_small") %>' runat="server" />
            </td>


            <td> <asp:Label ID="lbl_product_price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("txt_product_price") %>'></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt_product_price" Width="60px" BackColor="#d4d0c8" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "txt_product_price")%>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td> <asp:Label ID="lbl_stock" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("in_stock") %>'></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt_stock" BackColor="#d4d0c8" Width="60px" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "in_stock")%>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td> <asp:Label ID="lbl_type" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cate_type") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_type" runat="server" Width="60px" DataTextField="cate_type" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("int_product_id") %>' CommandName="edit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("int_product_id") %>' Visible="false" CommandName="update" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_cancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("int_product_id") %>' Visible="false" CommandName="cancel" runat="server">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("int_product_id") %>' CommandName="delete" OnClientClick='javascript:return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")'  runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

            </td>


        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
             <tr style="background-color:#15880a">
             <td colspan="8"> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_del_selected" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("int_product_id") %>'  OnClientClick='javascript:return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")' runat="server" OnClick="lnk_del_selected_Click">Deleted Selected</asp:LinkButton>
```

> Behind Code

```
      protected void chk_select_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control header_control = Repeater_product_detail.Controls[0].Controls[0];   // Find header Template's Items

    CheckBox chk = header_control.FindControl("chk_select") as CheckBox;
    if (!chk.Checked)
            {
                toggleCheckState(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleCheckState(true);
            }
}
```

public void toggleCheckState(bool checkstate)
   {

```
   foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater_product_detail.Items)   // Find Item Template's Items
   {
       if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
       {
           CheckBox chk_delete = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkDelete");
           chk_delete.Checked = checkstate;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please share you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your question, I believe, is:

"when i select any value from drop down i load some data from database that depends on this selected value, i am facing a problem whenever selection changes page will be refreshed."

There are many ways to accomplish this, but it might require some restructuring to produce the desired effect. A relatively simple way to do this would be:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_select" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_select_CheckedChanged"/>                  
           </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
                <asp:Asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="chk_select" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
           </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoPostBack="false"` in checkbox properties.

Answer (score 1):

Set the AutoPostBack property to false on the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was almost correct, except the ASP.NET checkbox doesn't have a SelectedIndexChanged event. It should be CheckedChanged

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_select" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_select_CheckedChanged"/>                  
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:Asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="chk_select" eventname="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

set value of  `Autopostback` attribute of `checkbox` which causing `postback` to `false`

Comment: I did.. but checkbox didn't respond after set post back 'false'

Answer (score 0):

You can set AutoPostBack property of CheckBox to false or else you can also use Ajax UpdatePanel control and put your CheckBox inside it so that whole page will not be reloaded and only checkbox value will be refreshed.

Comment: In your toolbox inside AJAX Extensions tab you will find UpdatePanel control. Inside it you can put Repeater control.

Comment: Thank you @netX  its working . but one problem is there.. when i run particulate one page of project then run easily.. but when i run whole project with F5 key then i got error (ERROR: Unknown server tag Update panel, Script manager)